# OBJ import coordinates

Tags: coordinates, obj

Importing OBJ files in blender gives positions that don't (textually) match the `.obj` file.
That is to say, a vertex that has position `(1,2,3)` is imported with coordinates `(1,-3,2)` (I think, this is what I want to check).

As far as I can tell, this transform the importer applies is
`(x,y,z) -> (x,-z, y)`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import an obj there are some transform setting on the right side of the file picker:

[image: File picker showing obj transform settings]

As you can see, the default are '-Z forward' and 'Y up'.  Any of these can be changed, but the default does amount to `(x,y,z) -> (x,-z, y)`, yes.

Comment: I didn't notice that. Thanks